# Githubにてダウンロードしたプロジェクト内にテキストデータしか入ってない

Tags: unity3d, github, unity2d

https://github.com/momokogumi/Sukebo-sample-game

上記のサイトからUnityのプロジェクトをZipファイルでダウンロードし、解凍して開きました。
しかし画像データが壊れてしまっています。

文字データしか入ってません。

動作環境はWindow10、ver2018.2です。

[image: まっしろ]

Answer (score 4):

該当のpngファイルは「Git LFS」として登録されており、これが原因で単純にZIPファイルでダウンロードするとうまく開けないようです。
(私もGit LFSについてはまだ詳しくないのですが、ファイルの実体ではなくそこに"ファイルがある"という情報だけが記録されているような状態)

Git LFSの問題としてissueが立っていました。
["Download zip" button doesn't get lfs files #903](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/903)

なお、対策としてはgitコマンドの`git clone`でリポジトリをローカルに取得すれば正常に開くことができました。

あなたがgitを使えるなら上記の通り`git`コマンドを使用するか、リポジトリは特に大きなファイルが登録されている様子も無いので、Git LFSを無効にした状態で管理するようにできないかを作者に問い合わせてみてください。
(名前を拝見するともしかしてご本人だったりしますか…？)

Comment: 解答ありがとうございます。GitLFSを使っていると、開けたいという画像ファイルのようなものが含まれないということですね！

本人です！実をいうと、GitLFSを使った記憶がないです！大変恐縮なのですが、GitLESを無効化するのに参考になる記事を教えていただきたいです！

Comment: すいません！解決しました！ありがとうございます。非常に感謝します！

Comment: 私の投稿はヒントの一部に過ぎないので、もしよければご自身で解決に至った手順を個別の回答として投稿してもらうと同じ問題が起きたユーザの助けになると思います。

Comment: 本当にそのままでgitコマンドのgit cloneでリポジトリをローカルに取得するだけなんですよ！ありがとうございました！